# C - Pointer threedimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have read throught a lot of articles explaining the concept of pointers, but i am not able to find out, why my code gives me an "incompatible pointer type" warning. Hopefully you guys can help me.

```
int cube[3][2][4] = {{{1,2,3,4}},{{2,3},{4,6,8,10}},{{3,4,5,6},{6,8,10}}};
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
int z = 1;
int *p = &cube[0][0][0];
int (*vptr)[2][4] = cube[x][y]; //This line throws a warning, when i compile it.
int (*mptr)[4] = cube[x];
```

Then i would like to access cube[x][y][z] with my pointers p, vptr, mptr. I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
printf("%d",*(*(*(p+x)+y)+z));
printf("%d",*(vptr+z));
printf("%d",*(*(mptr+y)+z));
```

I have read online, that you can access an array element like this:

```
*(*(array + row) + col)
```

But my code doesn't work. The first printf throws an error "invalid type argument of unary" and the second printf doesn't work, but the third works. I don't understand this. I would really appreciate it, when someone could explain this behaviour to me or can link me an explanations.

Thank you for your time and your help.
Greetings Mike.

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Comment: Your definition `int (*vptr)[2][4] = cube[x][y];` doesn't make sense. You're assigning an integer to some array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have probably meant is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int cube[3][2][4] = {{{1,2,3,4}},{{2,3},{4,6,8,10}},{{3,4,5,6},{6,8,10}}};
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 1;

    int *p = &cube[0][0][0];
    int (*vptr)[2][4] = cube;
    int (*mptr)[4] = cube[x];

    printf("%d\n", *p);
    printf("%d\n", *(*(*(vptr+x)+y)+z));
    printf("%d\n", *(*(mptr+y)+z));

    return 0;
}
```

This line:

```
int (*vptr)[2][4] = cube[x][y];
```

does not do what you want. The value of `cube[x][y]` has type `int *`, which does not match to declared type of `vptr` (pointer to two-elements array of four-elements arrays of type `int`).

In order to print `int` value with `%d` format specifier and `vptr` you can access it by either:

`vptr[x][y][z]`,

or

`*(*(*(vptr+x)+y)+z))`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first printf is that `cube` is not an array of pointers to an array of pointers to an array of int. In memory it is an array of integers. When you cast it to the int* the compiler interprets it as a array of int, a 1D array to be precise. Thats why `*(*(array + row) + col)` doesn't works.

The first printf statement should be

```
printf("%d", *(p + x*2*4 + y*4 + z));
```